# Rails HABTM: Post.title uniqueness per User only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, unique, has-and-belongs-to-many

In Rails 4, I have a typical HABTM setup;

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end
```

I'm wanting to validate the uniqueness of `Post.title`, but only on a per `Author` basis. So;

- Author #1 can have Post.title 'My Post'
- Author #2 can have Post.title 'My Post'
- but, Author #1 can not create a second Post with title 'My Post'

A `Post` is allowed to have more than one `Author` so I can't just have a `belongs_to` and use `validates_uniqueness_of :title, scope: :author_id` and I'm not sure how best to do this with HABTM.

Is this possible with a `validates` or would I need a `callback` that first checks if the associated `Author` has a matching `Post.title` before saving?

---

**EDIT**

I used the following migration to set up the join table;

```
class CreateAuthorsPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authors_posts, id: false, force: true do |t|
      t.belongs_to :author, index: true
      t.belongs_to :post, index: true
    end
    add_index :authors_posts, [:author_id, :post_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can do what you want with pre-defined validators.

You can define a validation that uses a custom method (see [Active Record Validations documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods))

something like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  validate :uniqueness_of_title_and_author

  def uniqueness_of_title_and_author
    if author.posts.where(title: self.title).exists?
      errors.add(:title, "must be unique")
    end
  end

end
```

That'll be checked every time `#valid?` is called for a `Post`

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out the `if` condition. Could you update your answer to show how to check the :title for posts only by the author that is creating it? Also, I am generating the new post like this; `author.posts.create(...)`. Is that correct?

Comment: done; I believe that query should suffice for your requirements. And yes, `author.posts.create` is how I would add a new post by the author, unless you want to modify it *before* saving in which case you should do `author.posts.build`

Comment: Alas I'm still having trouble, receiving this error; `NameError: undefined local variable or method \`author' for #<Post:0x007fa0b37cd8e0>`

Comment: Ah right, because a post has many authors. Hmm. Do you have an `authors_posts` table that joins the `authors` and `posts` tables?

Comment: Yes, join table exists. I've updated my question with the migration code for reference.